# Find code that depends on .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis, .net-3.5

Is there a way to run some sort of code analysis to find code which will compile with .NET 3.5 SP1 but not 3.5 RTM?

FxCop works for assemblies introduced with SP1, but for code that simply calls new methods and properties it does not detect that usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can highlight this stuff with fxcop or VS team system.

Make sure you have a read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030356/get-vs-to-highlight-all-net-3-5-sp1-method-calls/1030830#1030830). There is a bug with the current rules that ship with fxcop, so you need to do a bit of hand holding to get it to work.